# Convert localhost listening port to remotely listening port in Windows

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, port-forwarding

I use Psiphon to circumvent censorship and it runs both HTTP and SOCKS proxy listening in localhost. I need to use the service from another machine in the network.

As the Psiphon's listening port are binded locally to 127.0.0.1, it isn't accessible from other machine in the network. Is there any easy way to convert the bind from localhost to network IP?

I tried running PuTTY, but it asks for a running SSH server for session. I tried Bitvise SSH client too, but it requires SSH server.

In Linux, I can achieve this using a simple command:

ssh -L 0.0.0.0:8080:127.0.0.1:8090 user@localhost

where 8080 is the listening SOCKS port which can be accessed from other machines in the network and the Psiphon proxy running in 127.0.0.1:8090.

How can I achieve this in Windows?

Comment: Try installing Cygwin and using its `sshd`.

Comment: Setting up Cygwin seems a tedious process. Any other simpler solution possible?

Comment: MobaSSH might work.  Very confident Cygwin would work exactly as you expect on Linux though.  Other option is to run a simple TCP proxy of which there are many on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by using Privoxy. 
https://www.privoxy.org/

Just change the Privoxy listener from 127.0.0.1:8118 to 0.0.0.0:8118 and set upstream proxy to localhost Psiphon port in the config.txt file. You're done. Now, you can use the HTTP proxy port 8118 from other devices in the network.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to access the service from devices in the same network, you don’t need to change nothing. 
Just run the command “ipconfig” in the command line and search for your IPv4 or IPv6 Adress in the section of your network for example if you are using WiFi just go to “Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection” and copy the IP ( for example: 192.168.1.74 ) and in the other device in the same network go to that IP and the port ( 192.168.1.74:8888 for example )! That’s it!

Comment: If is something wrong please tell me about it, please.

Comment: I didn't downvote. But, the Psiphon runs the proxy binded to localhost interface only, which makes it inaccessible from network.

Comment: Yes but I tried to launch a server in localhost in the port 5000 and in my device I can access it by going to localhost:5000 or 127.0.0.1:5000 and in my other device I used 192.168.1.74:5000 and it worked fine without any extra configuration. Maybe in Psiphon it doesn’t works but in theory it should.

Comment: It means your web server is listening to all interfaces, which isn't my case.

Comment: https://www.google.pt/amp/s/fossbytes.com/enable-built-windows-10-openssh-client/amp/

Comment: https://www.getfilecloud.com/blog/create-your-own-virtual-private-network-for-ssh-with-putty/